# Can i create a method for jTable without using rs2xml.jar?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-8.1

I am new to programming and I have coded a program using netbeans 8.1 . My program is for displaying all the relevant items to be searched in a jTable. And then we can select the specific item in another jTable. I used rs2xml to create a method for jTable and it works fine. But after i use it, my searching have gone wrong. It wont display the correct items for the search. when i remove rs2xml.jar from library search works correctly, but when i select the item, it won't display in jTable. I can't figure this out.

here is the code for the search item:

```
     private void txtSearchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      

    try {

        @SuppressWarnings("LocalVariableHidesMemberVariable")
        ResultSet rs = oilmart.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE Item_Name LIKE '%" + txtSearch.getText() + "%'");
        if (rs.next()) {

            billinfo();
            txtPlace.setText(rs.getString("Place"));
        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Result not found", null, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);

        }

    } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e) {
    }

    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

And this is the table method i created using rs2xml.jar:

```
    public void billinfo() {

    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tblBillinfo.getModel();
    dtm.setRowCount(0);

    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("LocalVariableHidesMemberVariable")
        ResultSet rs = oilmart.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE Item_Name LIKE '%" + txtSearch.getText() + "%'");

        while (rs.next()) {

            Vector v = new Vector();
            v.add(rs.getString("Item_No"));
            v.add(rs.getString("Item_Name"));
            v.add(rs.getString("Qty"));
            v.add(rs.getString("Price_per_Qty"));
            v.add(rs.getString("Place"));

            buy_price = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Price_per_Qty"));

            dtm.addRow(v);
            tblBillinfo.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

And this is for selecting the specific item:

```
     private void tblBillinfoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    x++;

    int r = tblBillinfo.getSelectedRow();

    String no = tblBillinfo.getValueAt(r, 0).toString();
    String name = tblBillinfo.getValueAt(r, 1).toString();
    String buy = tblBillinfo.getValueAt(r, 3).toString();

    buy_price = (int) tblBillinfo.getValueAt(r, 3);

    String plc = tblBillinfo.getValueAt(r, 4).toString();

    tblBill.setValueAt(no, x, 0);
    tblBill.setValueAt(name, x, 1);
    tblBill.setValueAt(buy, x, 2);
    txtPlace.setText(plc);


}
```

Please help me to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "create a method for jTable"?

Comment: i have two tables in my interface. first one shows all the relevant items for the search. and the method is for the that table. when we click that table, the selected item will show on the other table.

Answer (score 1):

You have code (which appears to be correct) to add each row of data to the TableModel:

```
dtm.addRow(v);
```

But then your very next statement replaces the first row with the remaining rows of data in the ResultSet:

```
tblBillinfo.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

The result is that your TableModel will be missing the first row of data.

Just get rid of the above statement.

Comment: i have get rid of that statement, and checked the result. but it didn't changed the situation.